# Magento 2 How to create new order attribute programatically

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I've been searching the web on how to create an order attribute (if thats whats called), essentially I just want a new database column to appear in the sales_order database, obviously I could create it manually but is there a way I can create it via an upgrade script/programmatically?

Comment: This blog [How To Create Order Attribute Programmatically In Magento 2](https://www.mageants.com/blog/how-to-create-order-attribute-programmatically-in-magento-2.html)
helps admin to collect data of order attribute value which is select by customer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Practically, there are two main ways to add an order attribute (a new column) to order via an upgrade script.

--**Using $setup->getConnection()->addColumn()**

**app/code/Vendor/SalesOrder/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesOrder\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quote = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quote),
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );
        //Order table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

--**Using Quote and Sale Setup Factory**

**app/code/Vendor/SalesOrder/Setup/UpgradeData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesOrder\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    protected $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    protected $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory
     * @param SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Upgrades DB for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup $quoteInstaller */
        $quoteInstaller = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'quote_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup $salesInstaller */
        $salesInstaller = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        //Add multiple attributes to quote 
        $entityAttributesCodes = [
            'custom_attribute' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'custom_attribute1' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT

        ];

        foreach ($entityAttributesCodes as $code => $type) {

            $quoteInstaller->addAttribute('quote', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length'=> 255, 'visible' => false, 'nullable' => true,]);
             $salesInstaller->addAttribute('order', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length'=> 255, 'visible' => false,'nullable' => true,]);
            $salesInstaller->addAttribute('invoice', $code, ['type' => $type, 'length'=> 255, 'visible' => false, 'nullable' => true,]);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just about to add a solution.

Comment: This is only for creating an empty extra column in order table right? How can we copy the data from a custom attribute into this extra column in order table?

Comment: What is the better of the two ways?

Comment: Is this attribute pass in any third party order manage api?

Comment: Works fine thanks.

Answer (score 16):

> Magento 2.3.4 do not support above format:

Please check below steps to add **new attribute** to sales_order, quote and sales_invoice tables.

> Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Order">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="note" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Note"/>
    </table>
    <table name="quote" resource="checkout" engine="innodb" comment="Quote">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="note" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Note"/>
    </table>
    <table name="sales_invoice" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Invoice">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="note" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Note"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

> After that please run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

Comment: reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: What about the DataPatchInterface? the same procedure to add a new customer attribute? AFAIK, this way is for Magento 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Create a setup/upgrade script using `\Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory` and create an event for `sales_order_save_before` to set the new attribute.