# Magento 2 new order attribute

Tags: magento2, orders, setup-script

I have been trying to create a new order attribute in Magento 2, but not successful yet.

I have created a new module and this is already showing.

I added the different codes available in my setup `InstallData.php` but nothing worked so far.

Anybody who have successfully created an **order attribute**?

This is one of the code I have tried in `InstallSchema.php`

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
   public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('quote'),
        'delivery_eta',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'nullable' => false,
            'comment' => 'Delivery ETA',
        ]
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
        'delivery_eta',
        [
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'nullable' => false,
            'comment' => 'Delivery ETA',
        ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema scripts is to create a database structure. For example, creating a table and add columns to existing table. The install data scripts is to manage the data within existing tables, adding some sample data to tables.

At first time, we run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, Magento will execute the files in following order: (Creating table structure first, and then add the data to table)

- InstallSchema.php
- UpgradeSchema.php
- InstallData.php
- UpgradeData.php

In the next time, run setup upgrade command again, only two files:

- UpgradeSchema.php
- UpgradeData.php

So in your case, when editing the install data script that will not effect your database anymore. If we want to re-install, we may need to remove our module from table `setup_module` table (and, may need to remove the old database). And run setup upgrade command again.

For the adding new order attribute, we should take a look: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131969/33057

Comment: Thank you so much. As you mentioned the 'setup_module' table was preventing my install script from running.Deleted the table entry and now all is set..Also one moe query  if i need to add another attribute i should be using the UpgradeSchema.php set up right..?

Comment: Yes, you have to use **UpgradeSchema.php** to add another attribute but you also have to change module version (increasing it) or delete entry in `setup_module` table again.

Comment: @GeethikaAntony it depends, if you don't try to create new column, we can use `UpgradeSchema.php`. I'm not sure for all attributes. We need to check again. For example, add new product attribute, we don't need to use `UpgradeSchema.php`, we should use install data script.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh yes I would like to add another column to the quote and order table. Actually i still did not get the difference between  the  usage of `UpgradeSchema.php`  and `UpgradeInstall.php`. Shall try the different scenarios and update here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below steps to add a new attribute to sales_order, quote, and sales_invoice tables according to the new db_schema.xml format.

> Custom/Module/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Order">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="custom_attribute" nullable="true" length="255" comment="custom attribute"/>
    </table>
    <table name="quote" resource="checkout" engine="innodb" comment="Quote">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="custom_attribute" nullable="true" length="255" comment="custom attribute"/>
    </table>
    <table name="sales_invoice" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Invoice">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="custom_attribute" nullable="true" length="255" comment="custom attribute"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

> After that please run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command.