# Magento 2 saving custom attribute to sales_order_items

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, sales-quote

I have a *custom attribute* of a product, that I want to have it's value stored in **sales_order_items**. I have added an extra column in the table **sales_order_items**. But How can I store the value of that *custom attribute* into this extra column in **sales_order_items**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom order attribute for it. And then programmatically assign value for it.

You can follow given thread to create order attribute.

[Magento 2 How to create new order attribute programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131935/magento-2-how-to-create-new-order-attribute-programatically)

Comment: I have already created the custom attribute, as well have I also added an extra column in the sales_order_items. I want to know how to copy the data from custom attribute to the sales_order_items. I think the link you attached on shows how to created an extra column in database table, which I have already been able to do.

Comment: I need the same. please