# Magento 2: Plugin to add data to quote_address table when Place Order clicked

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, billing-address

What method do I need to observe to create a 'before' plugin to add data to the Billing Address data in the quote_address table when a user clicks the 'Place Order' button?

I'd prefer to use a plugin instead of an oberserver, as I've read it's best practice to use plugins where possible (to avoid conflicts with other third-party extending code/observers etc).

Answer (score 0):

Orders are saved trough `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` its `save` function

I think you understand how plugins work? Do i need to explain it in more details?

Comment: Hmm but that's to save the order, right? Would it not be best to save my custom data to the quote_address table when Place Order has been clicked and then observe another method when order success occurs – and then copy the custom data from quote_address to sales_order_address?

Comment: For what reason exactly do you want to do this? In other terms , what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to save some custom data the user adds on the checkout (in a custom input). I, eventually, will pull this into the admin Order Grid. 
My plan (How I think I should do it): The custom input will be placed on the billing step of the checkout, so I would like to add the info to the billing address data tuple in the order_quote when the user clicks Place Order. Then, once they've made a (successful) payment, manually move the custom data from quote_address to the sales_order_address table at the same time as default checkout data is copied across. 
Very happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Well that depends what kind of custom data.I need more information about what kind of data you want the user to add to the order.

Comment: It'll be a text input for them to add any additional info ('Leave item with concierge / at reception' etc) they might want to add. It won't be a required field. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No idea why you want to add that to the addresses. Just a new order attribute like i said : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131935/magento-2-how-to-create-new-order-attribute-programatically. And next save that attribute in your plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68945/discussion-between-swat-be-and-mikemason).