# Add Custom Attribute To Order

Tags: magento2

I'm looking for a way to add a custom attribute to the order entity in Magento 2.2.1. We have multiple stores setup in our Magento instance and want to be able to save a certain id to each order depending on what store the order was placed in. I have done some research online about doing this but have yet to find anything that helps, any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is a solution here , https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131969/31830