# Add custom attribute to myorder magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, customer-account, custom-attributes

How to add custom attribute like country of manufactured into my order page in customer panel magento2.1?
Also i want to add configurable variations into my order page, EX: bought T-shirt red size m it should show on my order page.

Comment: order page means checkout page ???

Comment: no customer account my order tab

Comment: Refer this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131935/magento-2-how-to-create-new-order-attribute-programatically

Comment: No, I want to show some custom attributes in my order page not create them... for example description is an attribute. i want to show it in myorder page

Comment: please attach screen shot where you need to display custom attribute